# TypeScript: Array Assignment

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a TypeScript class with an object property.  The properties inside this property have the type Array.  I expected to be able to add instances of my FlowConnection class to these arrays like I would in JavaScript, but the following code produces a compiler error:

```
export class FlowComponent{
    protected connectionPoints = {
        input: Array<FlowConnection>(),
        output: Array<FlowConnection>()
    }

    addInput(newInput:FlowConnection):Array<FlowConnection>{
        var l = this.connectionPoints.input.length;
        return this.connectionPoints.input[l] = newInput;
}
```

The specific compiler error occurs on line 9 of the code above, and is as follows:

> error TS2322: Type 'FlowConnection' is not assignable to type 'FlowConnection[]'.

Trying to use Array.push instead of assigning to the index at the end of the array yields an even stranger result:

```
return this.connectionPoints.input.push(newInput);
```

> error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'FlowConnection[]'.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return this.connectionPoints.input[l] = newInput;` doesn't return an instance of an Array - nor does `return this.connectionPoints.input.push(newInput);` - do the push, then return!

```
this.connectionPoints.input.push(newInput);
return this.connectionPoints.input;
```

For reference:

```
return this.connectionPoints.input[l] = newInput; //returns newInput
return this.connectionPoints.input.push(newInput); //returns new array length
```

Comment: Thanks! The first compiler error makes much more sense now. For the second, I assume that Array.push returns the index that the new item was pushed to? (Easy enough to test for myself, so don't feel compelled to answer unless you want to :P )

Comment: @B1SeeMore -- I believe `Array.push` returns the new length of the array, not the index

Comment: Well, I feel especially bright today. :P No shortage of sites hosting JavaScript references - I should have just gone and looked it up.  Thanks for answering!

Comment: @B1SeeMore -- It's always the easy ones that get ya :D

Answer (score 0):

A concrete answer would be, the return value does not match your specified return type. The returned value is of type `FlowConnection` (when returning the assignment) but it expects `Array<FlowConnection>`.

Your example also misses a closing brace (curly bracket) to close the `addInput` function.

Theoretically, a modern more convenient type system could be designed where scalar types are considered to be constrained collection types with only one element. Unfortunately, TypeScript's type system doesn't go that far.